# C# mix timer and loop

Tags: c#, loops, timer

I am creating a self enrollment system for a biometrics system.
I was trying to create a loop mix with timer.
I want to capture an image then stop the timer, and wait for 5 sec and capture again for 5 times. 
I was trying to use thread.sleep, but it will make my picturebox stop streaming the video.
But according to the codes below, it will straight away capture 5 images , and non-stop looping. Please correct me. Thanks
(5 sec timer > capture > timer stop ) * 5 times and finally all stop

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int a = 1;

   /* while loop execution */
   while (a < 5)
   {
        CaptureFunction();
        a++;
        timer1.Stop();
   }
   timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question...

Comment: if the timer's interval is 5 seconds then most of your code you don't need, you just need to show a new picture, Your messagebox.show may also screw up your timing

Comment: Sorry guys, the message box just for my testing purpose while i was finding solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the timer's interval so it only fires every 5 seconds:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval(v=vs.100).aspx

5000 is equivalent to 5 seconds.
Then use this code:

```
int photosTaken = 0;

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CaptureFunction();
     photosTaken++;
     if(photosTaken == 5) { timer.Stop(); }
}
```

If you wish to capture another 5, use this function:

```
private void capture5()
{
     photosTaken = 0;
     timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: it goes the same pharap its like i did this: timer1.Enabled = a == 5 ? false : true; also does the work.i tried the code and it works its probable some settings in timer....

Comment: @terrybozzio Instead of timer.Enabled = (a==5)?false:true; it would make more sense to write timer.Enabled = !(a==5);

Comment: yes,and i just made that as an example like yours,and what does that or mine produces?....the same result....that was my point in the first place(i was not trying to say your answer was wrong just the end result was the same),thank you.

Comment: +1 david if you read this pharap is more complete since he provided you to take another 5 pics.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve:

```
    int a = 1;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if(a <= 5)
         {
            CaptureFunction();
            a++;
         }
         else
            timer1.Stop();
         //place this just in case....
    }
```

oh...and if you really want to place the messagebox,place it after the increment(a++).

Comment: So Sorry, i made a mistake just now, the message box just for my testing purpose. I want to make it stop taking picture after 5 images taken. I tried the codes, but it keep taking pic non stop, any idea?

Comment: then maybe the problem is in capturefunction,since in this code only until a is 5 will execute those lines.

Comment: this is my capture function    
private void CaptureFunction()
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                PlayShutter();
                string strGrabFileName = String.Format(@"c:\\Users\\user99\\Desktop\\Data Collection\\{1}_{2}_{0:yyyy_MM_dd_hh.mm.ss.fff}.bmp", DateTime.Now, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(strGrabFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

               
            }
        }

Comment: I added MessageBox.Show(a.toString()); to check the value of a.

Comment: please test the edit above but just for test remove capturefunction and place   this.Text = a.ToString(); , and place the messagebox after increment(since its after increment it will show 2,3,4,5,6).

Comment: oh and like pharap said set interval .

Comment: I leave the "declare a" inside the function, thank you terry and so sorry.

Comment: Your solution works , just my stupid mistake. so sorry. i think is time to get some rest for myself.